# How to handle the different timezone in mysql?

Tags: mysql

user login from india at 9:00 am
other user from usa at other time.

how handle this if both the user having same server but login from different timezone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store timezone offset for each user (make the user select one timezone when he creates the account) and do the transformations based on that

Comment: This is not a good practice, because the timezone offset changes twice a year in the U.S., and in ways that are not easily predictable. (Meaning they change at the whim of the government).  It is far better to store in UTC, and convert using a standard timezone library, which is well maintained and updated whenever world governments change their minds about daylight savings times or timezone boundaries.

Comment: I think his problem is that he does not know the client location so he can compute (with libraries or not) user's time. The solution would be to store the location, then, with the help of libraries do the transformations

Comment: Am I missing something? It seems that can't possibly be his problem, because he says he's using a single server--so he knows when they connect to the server, according to the server's clock. Even if that was his problem, he can't store their timezone offset if he doesn't know where they're connecting from.

Comment: He could make the user chose a prefered timezone - and transform the time to that

Comment: Choosing a preferred timezone is a fine thing to do--as a display preference. The times should still be stored in UTC. Ask anyone who's developed an application that has to work across timezones, and I'll wager they'll say the same thing.

Comment: I agree with you with the UTC storing

Answer (score 3):

You haven't really told us what your problem is, but the best way to handle multiple timezones is to always store your timestamps in UTC, and convert from local to UTC on insert, and from UTC to local for display.

Comment: actually what happens that suppose i m logging in 9:30 am(gmt) from india.and logintime save in the server place in usa.so when i saw the past login time in the application i got wrong result like 12:30 am which mean i worked in night(in india) which is not feasible..i save the time in utc format and the fetch the resule as  cast(CONVERT_TZ(REPLACE(max(TimeStamp),'+00:00',''),'+00:00','{2}') as datetime) as DDateTime where {2} is offset                               i also use the below format              cast(CONVERT_TZ(max(TimeStamp),'+00:00','{2}') as datetime) as DDateTime,

Comment: Make sure all of your times are properly converted from local to UTC before storing them.